# strange behaviour when shift delete in windows explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, shift

I am getting some strange behaviour when trying to shift delete in file explorer.

Usually, I get the normal behaviour. I press shift delete and it perm deletes the file. If it's big enough, or there are confirmations I need to click I can actually see it get deleted -it takes time.

But when I tried this today, the file or even folder just disappears like it's gone to the recycle bin. But it hasn't gone there, I checked - and anyway I have it set up so anything deleted from this drive gets perm deleted straight away. But the point is, yesterday I could see it was going through a process to actually delete the file, but today it's just gone. Like it's just adjusting the FAT or something?

Has anyone else seen this behaviour?

Comment: Windows 10?  Run DISM and SFC:  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the comment. It's in the process of running now, I'll let you know how it goes. But in the meantime, can you explain what it was I just did? Just an overview/quick explanation, or signpost me on to other resources - just so I am learning something. Thanks so much.

Comment: DISM and SFC are initial repair steps and the first thing to run. Repairs get more serious if that does not work.

Comment: Here is a decent tutorial link on using DISM:  https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on windows - right click recycle bin and check if:

- "don't move files to recycle bin" is checked
- "display delete confirmation dialog" is not checked

These two selections together make the confirmation dialogue on shift-delete to no longer appear

Check and set the options as desired for each drive present in the recycle bin since it has separate settings for each drive/partition.

PS: the scandisk suggestion is not useful and won't find the cause since it's caused by this specific setting and not a system file error.

Comment: That was it. I definitely didn't change these settings myself. I have been a bit worried lately that someone has access to my system. My girlfriend uses my PC sometimes for work. But I noticed things like remote USB apps, screen mirroring, VM machines. I am not 100%, but it's looking v suspicious. As I say, my GF uses it for work and has to have zoom calls etc, so it's conceivably that. But my spidey sense is def twitching. And this is just another example of strange behaviour that I haven't seen before and I def didn't change those settings. Anyway - I'll keep vigilant. Thanks for your help.

Comment: oh - also, if anyone has any advice regards if I have a real problem or are just being paranoid - that would also be gratefully received. How can I tell if someone is really messing with me, or am I imagining it all??

Comment: if you or your girlfriend (check with her) did not change the setting, you could install malwarebytes and do a deep scan (it has a trial period as i recall). not necessarily a hacker but maybe a malware program messing with your system.

Comment: thanks, CrazyEyesDave - I will give that a go.